# Strange behavior of String.Equals?

Tags: c#, .net, string, object, equals

I have a dictionary that has keys as string.

One item has peculiar behavior. For the same string, it is not matching. I guess this has something to do with String.Equals behavior.

Even String.Equals is returning wrong result. (I am aware of String intern concept, but this seems to be different issue).

Check the image(watch window) for the issue. 
[image]

I am filling mappings dictionary (from xml resource file) as

```
var data = XDocument.Parse(str).Element(RootForXMLValidation).Elements().Where(x => x.Attribute("EcbFieldId") != null);
mappings = data.ToDictionary(x => x.Attribute("BoeField").Value.Trim(),
           x => new Mapping { Key = x.Attribute("BoeField").Value.Trim(),
           Type = (MappingType)Enum.Parse(typeof(MappingType), 
           x.Attribute("mappingType").Value), MappingDetail = x });
```

Why String.Equals behaving this way?

Comment: I am sorry, but even in your screenshot the strings are different. One is a hyphen-minus, the other seems like an en dash (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash)

Comment: Your are right. I had matched it in notepad, where both seems same (in the font I was using). For the sake of screenshot I had shared VS watch window, and later realized the difference.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The dash in `key` seems to be an em dash whereas the other is a hyphen.

Comment: Your are right. I had matched it in notepad, where both seems same (in the font I was using). For the sake of screenshot I had shared VS watch window, and later realized the difference.